# Keras Transfer Learning Resnet50 using fit_generator got high acc but low val_acc problem

Tags: python, keras, resnet, transfer-learning

I'm using Resnet50 model to do transfer learning, using 100,000 images in total of 20 scenes(MIT Place365 dataset). I trained only the last 160 layers(due to the memory restriction). The problem is I got a pretty high accuracy but extremely low validation accuracy, I think this might be an overfitting problem but I don't know how to solve it. I will really appreciate if anyone can give me advice about how to solve my low val_acc problem, thank you very much.
My code is as follows:

```
V1 = np.load("C:/Users/Desktop/numpydataKeras_20_val/imgonehot_val_500.npy")
V2 = np.load("C:/Users/Desktop/numpydataKeras_20_val/labelonehot_val_500.npy") 


net = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

x = net.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output_layer = Dense(20, activation='softmax', name='softmax')(x)
net_final = Model(inputs=net.input, outputs=output_layer)

for layer in net_final.layers[:-160]:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in net_final.layers[-160:]:
    layer.trainable = True

net_final.compile(Adam(lr=.00002122), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

def data_generator():
    n = 100000
    Num_batch = 100000/100
    arr = np.arange(1000)
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    while (True):
        for i in arr:
            seed01 = random.randint(0,1000000)

            X_batch  = np.load( "C:/Users/Desktop/numpydataKeras/imgonehot_"+str((i+1)*100)+".npy" )
            np.random.seed(seed01)
            np.random.shuffle(X_batch)

            y_batch = np.load( "C:/Users/Desktop/numpydataKeras/labelonehot_"+str((i+1)*100)+".npy" )
            np.random.seed(seed01)
            np.random.shuffle(y_batch)

            yield X_batch, y_batch

weights_file = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Transfer_learning_resnet50_fit_generator_02s.h5'
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=5, mode='auto', verbose=2)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(weights_file, monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, verbose=2)
callbacks = [early_stopping, model_checkpoint]

model_fit = net_final.fit_generator(
    data_generator(),
    steps_per_epoch=1000,
    epochs=5,
    validation_data=(V1, V2),
    callbacks=callbacks,
    verbose=1,
    pickle_safe=False)
```

The followings are the printouts:

```
Epoch 1/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3481s 3s/step - loss: 1.7917 - acc: 0.4757 - val_loss: 3.5872 - val_acc: 0.0560

Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.05600, saving model to C:/Users/Desktop/Transfer_learning_resnet50_fit_generator_02s.h5
Epoch 2/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 4884s 5s/step - loss: 1.1287 - acc: 0.6595 - val_loss: 4.2113 - val_acc: 0.0520

Epoch 00002: val_acc did not improve from 0.05600
Epoch 3/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 4964s 5s/step - loss: 0.8033 - acc: 0.7464 - val_loss: 4.9595 - val_acc: 0.0520

Epoch 00003: val_acc did not improve from 0.05600
Epoch 4/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 4961s 5s/step - loss: 0.5677 - acc: 0.8143 - val_loss: 4.5484 - val_acc: 0.0520

Epoch 00004: val_acc did not improve from 0.05600
Epoch 5/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 4928s 5s/step - loss: 0.3999 - acc: 0.8672 - val_loss: 4.6155 - val_acc: 0.0400

Epoch 00005: val_acc did not improve from 0.05600
```

Answer (score 1):

Following https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9214#issuecomment-397916155 it seems that batch normalization should be trainable.

The following code can replace the loop where you set/unset trainable layers:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    if hasattr(layer, 'moving_mean') and hasattr(layer, 'moving_variance'):
        layer.trainable = True
        K.eval(K.update(layer.moving_mean, K.zeros_like(layer.moving_mean)))
        K.eval(K.update(layer.moving_variance, K.zeros_like(layer.moving_variance)))
    else:
        layer.trainable = False
```

On my own data, I needed to reduce batch size to avoid OOM, and I now have:

```
Epoch 1/10
470/470 [==============================] - 90s 192ms/step - loss: 0.3513 - acc: 0.8660 - val_loss: 0.1299 - val_acc: 0.9590
Epoch 2/10
470/470 [==============================] - 83s 177ms/step - loss: 0.2204 - acc: 0.9163 - val_loss: 0.1276 - val_acc: 0.9471
Epoch 3/10
470/470 [==============================] - 83s 177ms/step - loss: 0.2219 - acc: 0.9184 - val_loss: 0.1048 - val_acc: 0.9589
Epoch 4/10
470/470 [==============================] - 83s 177ms/step - loss: 0.1813 - acc: 0.9327 - val_loss: 0.1857 - val_acc: 0.9303
```

Warning, it may impact accuracy and you must freeze your model to avoid weird inference. But it seems to be the only way that worked for me.

Another comment https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9214#issuecomment-422490253 only checks the layer names to set it trainable if it's a batch normalization, but it didn't changed anything for me. Maybe it can help for your dataset.

Comment: Brilliant. Just one thought. How about change K.zeros_like(...) for moving_variance to K.ones_like(...). Because if you look at the tensorflow document about BN, moving_variance is initialized by ones.